# Resgatar informações do Firebase em uma TextView no Android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase, firebase-database

Tudo bem pessoal? Gostaria de resgatar as informações do Firebase em uma TextView no Android. Eu já consigo inserir as informações no Database, como mostro na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de "puxar" estas informações do "nome","raca","sexo", e outros, numa Activity para um **TextView**.
Alguém sabe como realizar isto? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Fiz algo assim:
`mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pets");

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // String playerName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Pets ModelPets = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pets.class);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNomePet)).setText(ModelPets.getNome());
            }`


Porém o texto fica nulo ao executar, não aparece nada no TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte forma, populando uma lista e atribuindo os valores desta lista aos textviews do XML:

```
    public class TelaApresentacoes extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView edtNome, edtRaca, edtSexo;
    ListView listV_dadosB;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabaseB;
    DatabaseReference databaseReferenceB;
    Pets petsSelecionadaB;
    private List<Pets> listPetsB = new ArrayList<Pets>();
    private ArrayAdapter<Pets> arrayAdapterPetsB;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyt_tela_apresentacoes);

        inicializarFirebase();
        eventoDatabase();

        edtNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNomePet);
        edtRaca = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblRacaPet);
        edtSexo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSexoPet);
        listV_dadosB = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_dados2);

        listV_dadosB.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                petsSelecionadaB = (Pets) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                edtNome.setText(petsSelecionadaB.getNome());
                edtRaca.setText(petsSelecionadaB.getRaca());
                edtSexo.setText(petsSelecionadaB.getSexo());

                Log.e(null, String.valueOf(position)); //apenas para setar log da posição
            }

        });

    }

    private void eventoDatabase() {
        databaseReferenceB.child("Pets").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listPetsB.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Pets p = objSnapshot.getValue(Pets.class);
                    listPetsB.add(p);
                }
                arrayAdapterPetsB = new ArrayAdapter<Pets>(TelaApresentacoes.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPetsB);
                listV_dadosB.setAdapter(arrayAdapterPetsB);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void inicializarFirebase() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(TelaApresentacoes.this);
        firebaseDatabaseB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabaseB.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        databaseReferenceB = firebaseDatabaseB.getReference();
    }}
```